# With Flask Sessions, do I need to explicitly create/change/delete cookies?

Tags: flask, cookies, session-cookies, python-3.11

I'm confused about cookies in relation to Flask sessions (hereinafter "sessions").
I do understand how sessions rely on client-side cookies.
My question is when we create/change/pop the value of a session variable, does that automatically create/set a cookie on the user's browser OR do I need to also explicitly manage a cookie to go with that session variable?

```
        session.permanent = True
        session["t_id_user"] = t_id_user
        # Is the following code needed?
        C = make_response("")
        cookie_expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)
        C.set_cookie("t_id_user", str(t_id_user), expires=cookie_expires)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the builtin and default Flask session implementation, any modifications to the `Session` object will automatically result in a Set-Cookie header in the response of the request that made the change.

So, you only need this code:

```py
session.permanent = True
session["t_id_user"] = t_id_user
```

The rest is automatic and handled for you. And in fact more secure. If you set `SECRET_KEY`, the session cookie will be signed (*not* encrypted) such that it can't be tampered with outside of the server environment.